# Both my comment on original question and a new question was deleted, what is the way ahead?

Tags: support

First of all, apologies if this sounds confusing. I read a question on `fit` and `fit_transform` at the below link:

[What's the difference between fit and fit_transform in scikit-learn models?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/whats-the-difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models)

I had a follow-up question related to the same topic, however, I didn't have enough karma to post it as a comment. So I posted my question as an answer and had mentioned the situation in the answer itself. I also requested if a moderator could turn it into a comment instead of a question because that's where it belongs. A moderator deleted it saying it was a follow-up question and so I need to ask it as a new question, and provide the reference to the original question (link given above). I didn't have the karma to undelete it, neither could I reach out to the moderator, so I did as he told me to:

[Follow Up Question - Why use fit when already have fit_transform?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/92968/follow-up-question-why-use-fit-when-already-have-fit-transform)

However, now this question too has been deleted saying that this is not an original question, and so should have been asked at the original question! I wrote to the Stack Overflow Team, however, they couldn't help much since they are not SMEs in these respective fields, so they pointed me to this Meta site.

I am posting about my dilemma here hoping for a solution, any solution.

P.S. Best part is, I even got the answer to my query in the post that I created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deletion of your first answer was appropriate since answers are not intended for follow-up questions or to circumvent reputation requirements for commenting.

The new question has been closed, not deleted. It is still visible and the community can choose to reopen the question (which they already have started to).

Comment: Thank you so much!